# Rails 3: Approach to Executing a Method/Script every 30 minutes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a database which, after 30 minutes from the rows `updated_at` time, I want to delete rows from the database. I know how to find rows based on this time, but I don't know a technique for actually deleting it on a timed interval.

What is a good method of achieving this? Is there something Rails-esque?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Delayed Job](https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job) is a common tool for this sort of thing.

You could make a simple class with a `perform` method to delete the entry:

```
class DeleteTheThing
  attr_accessor :thing_id

  def initialize(the_thing)
    @thing_id = the_thing.id
  end

  def perform
    # Delete the thing if it should still be deleted
  end
end
```

And then, when you decide that your object should be deleted, queue up your delayed task:

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue(
  DeleteTheThing.new(the_thing),
  :run_at => 30.minutes.from_now.getutc
)
```

Comment: mu do you prefer Delayed Job over Resque and if so any reasons to pick one over the other?

Comment: @Michael: I haven't done much with Resque, I haven't had any problems with DJ so "if it ain't broke, don't fix it".

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to use [Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque) which is like delayed job but better and simpler. [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/271-resque) is simple tutorial to start with. You can set Cron for setting interval of 30 mins.

Comment: In what respects is it simper.  mu's example is pretty simple.  I would like to learn about the differences between the two and if I should pick on to learn or if each one matches different needs better

Comment: Resque is more complex because it requires Redis in your server environment. I would only recommend it if you are already using Redis, or you need to process a very high volume of jobs.

Comment: @Michael Adam from Heroku has written a [nice article](http://adam.heroku.com/past/2010/4/13/rethinking_cron/) that differentiates between both.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use memcached instead of your db?  Then you could do something like

```
  def get_data(user)
    Rails.cache.fetch("cached_data-#{user.name}", :expires_in => 30.minutes) do
      ##  create some hash here
      {:name => user.name, :more_data => user.data}
    end
  end
```

The data would persist until the hash has not been used for 30 minutes.

---

if you do like Active record you could have a cron job every 5 minutes or so, but that doesn't scale well